# How to prevent the change event from firing if I assign a value dynamically to it but not clicked?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
 async onSectionRolesCheckBoxChange(item: ISectionRole, event) {
    if(!event) {
      return;
    }

<ion-checkbox slot="end" (ionChange)="onSectionRolesCheckBoxChange(item, $event)" 
        [checked]="item.selected">
        </ion-checkbox>
```

this event is supposed to be fired if I SELECT the checkbox but it keeps on firing even if I assign a value to the [checked] dynamically. It shouldn't. Only it should be fired I click check/uncheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the vanialla `click` event instead of the `ionChange` event. However the `$event` in this case would be the `MouseEvent`, so you'd be losing the `$event` from `ionChange` event.

Try the following

```html
<ion-checkbox 
  slot="end" 
  (click)="onSectionRolesCheckBoxChange(item, $event)" 
  [checked]="item.selected"
>
</ion-checkbox>
```

#### Update: get checkbox state

There are multiple methods to fetch current value of a tag. Better ways would be to use either a Reactive or template-driven form. Here I'd use a quick workaround using template reference variable to get the `checked` property of the tag.

```html
<ion-checkbox 
  #role
  slot="end" 
  (click)="onSectionRolesCheckBoxChange(item, role.checked)" 
  [checked]="item.selected"
>
</ion-checkbox>
```

```js
async onSectionRolesCheckBoxChange(item: ISectionRole, checked: boolean) {
  console.log(checked);
  // other statements
}
```

Comment: oh, i just need the checked/unchecked value, is it possible in mouse event?

Comment: @Ivan: Yes it's possible, I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks man. stay blessed.

Comment: there's one problem in it, when I uncheck the box the checked is going as true but if I check the checkbox the checked property is going as false.

Comment: also, to appear the check i need to click 2 times. Why not in a single time?